# Swift 3 Refactoring: "Type 'NSView' has no member ..." Error

Tags: swift, selector, swift3, nsview, swift-protocols

Before Swift 3, I created a private extension of `Selector` in my `NSRulerView` subclass that looked like this:

```
private extension Selector {
    static let shouldAddMarker = #selector(NSView.rulerView(_:shouldAdd:shouldAddMarker:))
    static let willAddMarker = #selector(NSView.rulerView(_:willAdd:atLocation:willAddMarker:atLocation:))
    static let didAddMarker = #selector(NSView.rulerView(_:didAdd:didAddMarker:))
}
```

This was convenient because I could simply use my private short member names to access a selector, like so:

```
if self.delegate?.respondsToSelector(.shouldAddMarker) == true {
    // I have a delegate and it conforms to the NSRulerMarkerClientViewDelegation protocol.
}
```

Now that I'm desperately trying to convert my existing Swift codebase to 3.0, `NSView` doesn't seemingly implement the aforementioned methods.

I know that `NSRulerMarkerClientViewDelegation` is an informal protocol, and its declared methods are implemented as an extension to NSView, but I don't see any API changes from Swift 2.x to 3.0 that would break my existing selectors.

Does anyone have a clue as to where I should go from here? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the new selectors for Swift 3:

```
private extension Selector {
    static let shouldAddMarker = #selector(NSView.rulerView(_:shouldAdd:))
    static let willAddMarker = #selector(NSView.rulerView(_:willAdd:atLocation:))
    static let didAddMarker = #selector(NSView.rulerView(_:didAdd:))
}
```

Comment: Gracias. I must have totally glossed over the actual selector names. Doh! I appreciate your help!

Comment: De nada, @BenStock.